# How to optimize weights of SVM with random search?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm using `sklearn.svm.SVC` for classification of 2, 3 and 4 classes with SVM.

`SVC` support as a parameter `class_weight` which I would like to use because I have heavy class imbalance (around 70% vs 30% for 2 classes). For optimizing the other paramters of the SVM (gamma and C) I'm using `RandomizedSearchCV`. For `param_distributions` of `RandomizedSearchCV` I'm currently using the following distributions:

```
mdl = svc(probability = True, random_state = 1)
RandomizedSearchCV(mdl, param_distributions = params, n_iter = 100, random_state = 1) 
params = {'clf__C': scipy.stats.expon(scale=100), 'clf__gamma': scipy.stats.expon(scale=.1), 'clf__kernel': ['rbf']}
```

what distributions should I add to `params` for `class_weight` if I'm using 2, 3 and 4 classes?

Comment: You can use mdl = SVC(probability = True, random_state = 1, class_weight='balanced') to penalize mistakes on the smaller classes by an amount proportional to how under-represented it is, i.e. n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y)) where y is the class label vector. GridSearchCV() is generally better than RandomizedSearchCV() if your data set isn't too big. Something like C and $\gamma$ on a log scale from $10^{-3}$ to $10^{3}$

Comment: @mathisfun But I would like to not only set the class_weights to balanced but optimize over the class weights. Regarding GridSearchCV() vs. RandomizeSearchCV(), I have some papers claiming that random search is always more efficient, with increasing efficiency exponentially if the number of hyperparameters grows.

Comment: Yes, it is much faster, but less likely to get you near an optimal solution, especially as the sample space of parameters grows. So it depends on how much time you have to train it, how fast your computer set up is, how big your dataset is, etc. I'm not sure about the class_weights as I normally just use balanced as it seems to be where the theory says the weight should be. You might want to ask this question over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ as they'll have stronger opinions about this.

Comment: @mathisfun I will ask over there. Let us assume that we have 3 parameters to optimize and we only choose 10 values each. That would imply that we already have 10^3 possible combinations and that with only 10 values. With increasing values and parameters it gets even worse.